# Plotly adding a frame to a figure

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

So I want simply to add a frame around my figure (2 geo-figures), as I drew in the picture below. When I try to add in the update_layout() borderwidth and color, it does not work.

Thank you in advance!

[image: My idea]

Comment: I think just adding some css targeting these elements or a container that holds the elements is the easier approach.

Comment: Can you also include the code you used to generate this figure? That would help in creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that people are more likely to answer your question